# How to read map of RGB image by using imread in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imread

after run this code the value of map variable is empty.please guide me for this.

```
[rgb,map] = imread('color.png');
```

Comment: If `map` is empty, then `rgb` is not an indexed image. Depending on its size it's either grayscale or truecolor. If you want to convert it to an indexed image use `rgb2ind`.

Comment: ok.rgb2ind needs the number of color (n) .how to determine suitable value for that parameter?

Comment: That would depend why you want an indexed image in the first place...